# A multi text field search bar using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am interested in building a search bar similar to Booking's (with multiple inputs). Additionally, the search bar should collapse to a single text field when clicked on search. Once clicked again it will expand. The textfields when clicked on should open the search view in spirit of the [Material design guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/search/overview).

What widgets do you recommend?

[image]